# Plane stretching not giving correct image texture

Tags: image

I have a plane with an image on it. I'm trying to stretch the plane, but the image isn't being stretched correctly:
[image: Blender image]

This is what I'm expecting:
[image: Expected results]

The plane is viewed Top Orthographic in the 3D Viewport. I tried adding a subdivision modifier, but no luck. Does anyone know how to fix this?